# Load other link after one is clicked in if else statement

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have these links, but I want them to load on the view whenever the other is clicked. So if the one in the if statement is clicked, I want the other one in the else statement be displayed on the view. And the other way around. How do I do this with my links? The onclicks are created with an AJAX request.

```
@{
    if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        if (ViewBag.Wishlist.Contains(item.id))
        {
            <a onclick="RemoveFromWishList(@ViewBag.OrderLine)" id="remove" class="btn btn-default swap swapHeart">
                <span style="color:#8F6B93;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
            </a>
        }
        else
        {
            <a onclick="AddToWishList(@item.id)" id="add" class="btn btn-default swap swapHeart">
                <span style="color:#8F6B93;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>
            </a>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using server-side code, use client.  Below the wishlist server-side variable initializes the style attribute with no style or a "display:none" style to hide the right link depending on whether the item is in the wishlist or not.

```
//This is server-side
bool wishlist = ViewBag.Wishlist.Contains(item.id);

<!-- Client side only but use server-side definitions inside to initialize -->
<a onclick="RemoveFromWishList(@ViewBag.OrderLine)" id="remove" class="btn btn-default swap swapHeart"
  style="@(wishlist ? "" : "display:none")">
    <span style="color:#8F6B93;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
</a>
<a onclick="AddToWishList(@item.id)" id="add" class="btn btn-default swap swapHeart"
  style="@(wishlist ? "display:none" : "")">
   <span style="color:#8F6B93;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>
</a>
```

Then on click, you can use JS to swap the other:

```
$("a.swapHeart").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).toggle();
  $(this).siblings("a.swapHeart").toggle();
});
```

As long as the links are true siblings, this should work.

Comment: And may I ask why server side code on the view isn't recommended?

Comment: Because you are essentially not rendering the other link; there is no link to show because it never rendered, so there is no other link to toggle.  This approach uses client-side logic to toggle both buttons.  I hope you understand my comment is not "server-side logic is bad" but in this case, server-side logic, based on your requirement of toggling the buttons, meant both buttons must be in the DOM and the server-side wasn't the best way (other than to show/hide at rendering time).